# How do I turn all words uppercase and in square brackets in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I know it sounds weird but I have a list of names (excluding surnames) and I need them all uppercase within square brackets. For example from `Michael` to `[MICHAEL]` for all words in all lines in the entire document.

What code can I use to replace all in Regular expression Search Mode?

Comment: It may not be the answer you are looking for, but what about writing a program which reads the characters one by one and transforms them to upper case.

Finally it writes them into a file.

Comment: @DavidWeber No, not the answer I was looking for. I'm not a programmer, plus I know there is a simple, easier way to do with Notepad++ I just don't know the exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for whole words:

```
([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
```

Replace them with this to add brackets and convert all letters to upper case:

```
[\U\1]
```